# калькулятор по формуле закона Ома на JS

Tags: javascript

как написать на JS
калькулятор который будет считать не достающие данные?
У нас есть

```
введите сюда код

Voltaje=6V
R¹=10
R²=5
R³=15
Rt=?
I=?
V¹²³=?
```

И мы ему вводим это

И он должен дать такие данные

```
Rt=R¹+R²+R³=10+5+15=30
I=V:R = 6/30 = 0.2
V¹= I*R¹=2
V²= I*R²=1
V³= I*R³=3
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO. Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. В будущем укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. В первый раз это будет подарком

Answer (score 0):

```js
let voltage = 6;
let r1 = 10;
let r2 = 5;
let r3 = 15;
let rt = r1 + r2 + r3;
let i = voltage/rt;
let v1 = i * r1;
let v2 = i * r2;
let v3 = i * r3;

console.log("Rt = " + rt);
console.log("I = " + i);
console.log("V1 = " + v1);
console.log("V2 = " + v2);
console.log("V3 = " + v3);
```

Comment: а как свои данные писать что бы это на сайте разместить и люди вводить могли вводить свои данные, я просто плохо очень знаю джава скрипт, я пытался такое написать  let rt = r1 + r2 + r3;
let i = voltage/rt;
let v1 = i * r1;
let v2 = i * r2;
let v3 = i * r3;

console.log("Rt = " + rt);
console.log("I = " + i);
console.log("V1 = " + v1);
console.log("V2 = " + v2);
console.log("V3 = " + v3);

Comment: но... огромное спасибо